# How can I bind WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn to ViewModel Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid in my view with a column that I want to be able to edit using a combobox. Do to so, I create a property on my viewmodel like this:

```
public List<EnumeradorWCFModel> TiposCarga { get; set; }
```

The property is filled correctly using a WCF service. Now this is my DataGrid definition:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TarifarioSel.TarifariosDet}" 
              IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="200" Header="Tipo Carga" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TiposCarga}" 
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=ID_TipoCarga}"  DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion" SelectedValuePath="ID"/>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I Also try this, with no luck:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TarifarioSel.TarifariosDet}" 
              IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="200" Header="Tipo Carga" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TiposCarga}" 
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=ID_TipoCarga}"  DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion" SelectedValuePath="ID"/>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The problem is how can i bind the ItemsSource Property of the combobox column to a property inside my viewmodel.

Any help please! Thanks!

Comment: At first look your binding seems good, (only the second). have you tried replacing the list with ObservableCollection or do you get binding error in the output?

Comment: Thanks @Esh, find it myself. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Find it myself, but don't know why it has to be made like this. I post the answer in case someone needs it.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TarifarioSel.TarifariosDet}" 
              IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                                
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="200" Header="Tipo Carga" 
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=ID_TipoCarga}"  DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion" SelectedValuePath="ID">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TiposCarga}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TiposCarga}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: It has to be done like this because the row, in which the ComboBox is placed, has a different DataContext. The row's DataContext is the particular element of the ItemsSource. And therefore you cannot bind to a property of the viewmodel.

Comment: Tranks. I now The datacontext is different if you see my second option should also Work but it doesnt.